# Customise Launcher to override default home key behaviour?

Tags: android

I want to write a customise launcher for ics 4.0 , but when i write the code for home key down it will show the option to complete action using selected launcher one the default installed on the device and the other one that i created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common thing. If multiple apps are available with same intent action and categories, then app manager will display the list of all apps to accept selection from user.

E.g., set wallpaper applications.

The default launcher app and your launcher app are with same intent action and categories, so that you are getting complete action dialog.

I hope it may help you to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: if there is any way to overcome this ? because i want my app to override the system default launcher

Comment: @vivek no you can not change the launch preferrences by your own without asking the user for it.

Comment: @akkis i just want to block that popup and when any one want to switch between these to launcher a password popup will be displayed and then any one with the correct password can switch over other

Answer (score 1):

```
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener numberCheckListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Check that the string is an integer
        if (newValue != null && newValue.toString().length() > 0
                && newValue.toString().matches("\\d*")) {
            return true;
        }
        // If now create a message to the user
        Toast.makeText(LiveWallpaperActivity.this, "Invalid Input",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: hey vipul i dont think its the write one but hope so i am overriding the onKeydipatch()